# Add Jtable to SWT Group

Tags: java, swing, jtable, swt

I have created a Jtable in Java RCP. I need to add the table to a Group

```
 private createview(Composite parent) {

       Group group = createGroup(parent, "Details");
       Button button3 = new Button(group, SWT.PUSH);
       button3.setText("demo");

       String[] columnNames = {"num","Address","name","Version"};
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames,0);
       Object[] objs = {"1","ff","aa","22" },
                        {"2","gg","cc","33"};
        tableModel.addRow(objs);
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
         group.pack();
    }
```

How to add the Jtable(table) to the group. The button added  is visible in the UI. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Adrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just mix SWT and Swing code like this.

It is possible to put Swing code in an SWT app by using the `SWT_AWT` bridge class but if possible you should avoid it.

SWT has the `Table` class for tables, or JFace has `TableViewer`.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 for your reply. I will then try with tableViewer